# How to fix ReferenceError: req is not defined Javascript

Tags: javascript, express

My `rankcard.js` code

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const canvacord = require("canvacord");

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render(image)
})

const data = {
  avatar: req.query.avatar,
  currentXP: req.query.currentXP,
  requiredXP: req.query.requiredXP,
  status: req.query.status,
  color: req.query.progressBarColor,
  username: req.query.username,
  discriminator: req.query.discriminator
}
const rank = new canvacord.Rank()
    .setAvatar(data.avatar)
    .setCurrentXP(data.currentXP)
    .setRequiredXP(data.requiredXP)
    .setStatus(data.status)
    .setProgressBar(data.color, "COLOR")
    .setUsername(data.username)
    .setDiscriminator(data.discriminator);
rank.build()
    .then(buffer => {
        const image = (buffer, 'rank.png');
    })

module.exports = router;
```

I tried so many ways to fix but i cant find the cause of [![this error][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioQQN.png

Comment: `req` is out of scope. Either move `const data = {}` inside the `router.get` callback, or assign `req` to a global variable

Comment: wait ill try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor this with function:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const canvacord = require("canvacord");

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render(image)

  const [data, rank] = getData(req);
})


function getData(req) {

const data = {
  avatar: req.query.avatar,
  currentXP: req.query.currentXP,
  requiredXP: req.query.requiredXP,
  status: req.query.status,
  color: req.query.progressBarColor,
  username: req.query.username,
  discriminator: req.query.discriminator
}
const rank = new canvacord.Rank()
    .setAvatar(data.avatar)
    .setCurrentXP(data.currentXP)
    .setRequiredXP(data.requiredXP)
    .setStatus(data.status)
    .setProgressBar(data.color, "COLOR")
    .setUsername(data.username)
    .setDiscriminator(data.discriminator);
rank.build()
    .then(buffer => {
        const image = (buffer, 'rank.png');
    })


return [data, rank];

}



module.exports = router;
```